# Calculating Different Investments altogether?

Tags: buy-bitcoins, investing

Bitcoin was my first dive into investing.

I am trying to see how much I made and how well I did.

I am getting a problem however where I bought multiple times at different periods and prices.

What's the standard way to calculate how well I did when each order was at different prices and etc?

So for example:

if I bought X BTC with Y USD at time t0 
and Z BTC with Y USD at time1

How would I calculate my return and profits?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a basic math question.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to calculate would be:

`averagecost = ((BTC[t0] x USD[t0]) + (BTC[t1] x USD[t1]) + (so on))/total_BTC`

where `t0`,`t1` and so on are different time when you bought.

The above gives you the average cost for all your BTC

Now to know the profit, use the below formula:

`profitloss = (current_BTC_price - averagecost) x total_BTC`

If `profitloss` is negative, then you have a loss.

If `profitloss` is positive, then you have a profit.